# laravel search paginate Call to undefined method links()

Tags: search, laravel, pagination

Hi I have implemented a search facility in laravel it returns the search query but I also get this error in my laravel log as follows:

```
 [2014-09-14 21:06:20] production.ERROR: exception 
 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined method 
  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links()' in 
  /media/sf_Sites/tempus/app/storage/views/424d7d6280a6a7c59b31268a6d17e44a:27
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

My code is as follows:

Projects/Index

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section("content")
<div class="container">
    <div>
        {{ Form::open(['method' => 'GET', 'class' => 'nav-bar-form navbar-right']) }}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::input('search', 'q', null,['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Search']) }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

        </div>

    </div>
    @if (Auth::check())
    @if (count($projects) > 0)
    @foreach ($projects as $project)
   <p> {{ $project->project_name }}</p>
    @endforeach
    @else
    <h5 class="errorslist">No match found</a></h5>
    @endif
    @endif

</div>
<div class="container">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li>{{ $projects->links() }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
{{ Form::close() }}

@stop
```

Repository

```
public function searchProjects($query){

    return \Project::where('project_name', 'LIKE', "%$query%" )
        ->orderby('project_name', 'asc')
        ->get();
}
public function getAll()
{

    // get all logged in users projects and paginate 9 per page
    return \Auth::user()->projects()->orderBy('project_name', 'asc')->paginate(9);
}
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
    {


$query = Request::get('q');

$projects = $query
    ? $this->project->searchProjects($query)
    : $this->project->getAll();

        echo View::make('projects.index', compact('projects'));


    }
```

Routes

```
Route::get('projects/index', array('before' => 'auth',
    "as"   => "projects/index",
    "uses" => "ProjectController@index"
));
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting an error when I perform a search query on my links method, any ideas?

Comment: Im not sure what the compact function does, but I think that you have to do something like $projects->paginate();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need paginate on your searchProjects method as well:

```
public function searchProjects($query){

    return \Project::where('project_name', 'LIKE', "%$query%" )
        ->orderby('project_name', 'asc')
        ->paginate(9);

}
```